# Are there any second chances to get new equipment in The Last of Us Part 2?

Tags: the-last-of-us-2

My wife and I are both playing The Last of Us Part 2, each with our own profile, effectively taking turns. We're also enjoying watching the other play, so we're sort of taking turns spoiling one another.

At one point I was playing a section my wife had already played. I'd cleared the area of enemies and was scouring the area for resources. However, I forgot there was an area I hadn't yet searched and went past a point-of-no-return. My wife screamed, but it was too late and I'd already triggered the checkpoint.

Ends up the area I forgot to search included a new weapon

> the trap mine

Does this mean I'll have to perform my entire playthrough without this item? I've done some googling for guides on where to find equipment and they all give only one location, so I'm feeling pessimistic. But I'm hoping they're only showing the first location for each item, but that I might find other copies elsewhere. If so, where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are! Or at least there was for my specific case.

> The trap mine is usually found on a bed in an apartment building during Seattle Day 1. I missed that, but found it on top of a workbench during Seattle Day 2. The workbench is inside a garage or something, which you access by rolling a dumpster to hop over the wall, you can't miss it, it's right in front of you in the main game play path.

> I later also missed a tech-tree book with Abby (apparently I kind of suck at this game), only to find it at the very next safe I opened.

I can't guarantee this works for all pieces of equipment, but if it worked for these two cases, it seems reasonable to assume that similar situations present themselves for other items as well.